# Docker seems to have no tty?

Tags: macos, docker, tty

I have a very simple docker file called "Yakkety", shown here:

```
FROM ubuntu:yakkety
RUN apt-get update
```

I can successfully create an image from this by running `docker build -f Yakkety -t my-yakk .`.  However, when I run a shell in this image, it can't seem to produce any output:

```
% docker run -t my-yakk /bin/bash
root@ab0f59b63159:/# ls
(hangs)
```

I have to exit the process by doing control-C.

I *think* this same process used to work for me under older versions of Docker, but I guess I can't be sure because it was a few months ago.

What can I do to diagnose the issue?

I'm using `Docker version 1.12.6, build 78d1802`, installed with `homebrew`.  I'm running on Mac OS X Version 10.12.2.

Comment: Try `-i -t`: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/

Comment: Oh!  That works.  I did consider that, but didn't try it - I guess I misunderstand what "attach" means.  The docs you reference say "If you do not specify -a then Docker will attach all standard streams."  I thought that would have me covered...

Comment: So I guess I was misdiagnosing this as a STDOUT problem when it was a STDIN problem?

Comment: Correct, it wasn't that the container did not respond, it was that it didn't receive your input.

Answer (score 1):

Try `docker run -it my-yakk /bin/bash`. When using only the `-t` flag, you get TTY but it is not interactive. This is why you need to use the `-i` flag as well.